# creating and displaying a linked list in c: program not displaying correctly

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

currently working on a program to create a poker game. Right now I'm trying to get the deck of cards to print. It's not printing anything, and instead of exiting with code zero when I run it, it exits with code -104356 or something like that. I'm using two functions, one to make the cards, and the other to print them, and I'm not sure where the problem is.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct card_s {
char suit;
int face;
struct card_s* next;
} card;

card* createCard(int n);
void printCard(card* head);

int main(void) {
card* first = NULL;

first = createCard(52);
printCard(first);

free(first);
return(0);
```

}

```
card * createCard(int n) {
int i = 0;
card* head = NULL;
card* tmp = NULL;
card* p = NULL;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tmp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    tmp->face = rand() % (10 + 1 - 1) + 1; //this is supposed to generate a random number between 1 and 10
    tmp->suit = "CDHS"[rand() % 4]; //this is supposed to generate a random letter C, D, H, or S
    
    tmp->next = NULL;
    
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tmp;
    }
    else {
        p = head;
        while (p != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        
        p->next = tmp;
    }
}
return(head);
```

}

```
void printCard(card * head) {
card* p = head;

while (p->next != NULL) {
    printf("%d%s\n", p->face, p->suit);
    p = p->next;
}
return;
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
else {
    p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    
    p->next = tmp;
}
```

after the while loop the pointer `p` is equal to `NULL`. So the next statement

```
    p->next = tmp;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need at least to rewrite the loop like

```
    while (p->next != NULL) {
        p = p->next;
    }
```

But in any case such an approach is inefficient. It is better to write

```
if (head == NULL) {
    head = tmp;
    p = head; 
}
else {
    p->next = tmp;
    p = p->next;
}
```

Also within the function `printCard` the last element of the list is not outputted due to the condition in the while loop

```
while (p->next != NULL) {
```

Also you may not use the conversion specifier `%s` with an object of the type `char` as you are doing

```
printf("%d%s\n", p->face, p->suit);
```

The function can be written like

```
void printCard( const card *head ) 
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next ) 
    {
        printf("%d%cn", head->face, head->suit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the potential issues with your implementation of the linked list, so I will chip in with a somewhat different point.

You might want to store your deck of cards in a linked list--I don't know your implementation, so whether that is a good idea or not, I cannot say, but it can certainly make sense--but this doesn't mean that you have to allocate each card separately or initialise them one by one. You can create a deck of cards as an array and still chain them up with pointers.

If you do that, you can allocate and free them as a whole, and you avoid the irritating special case when you wish to prepend/append to an empty list. You can have all your cards at once, and then chain them up.

Such an approach might also make it easier to shuffle the cards. With an array, you can easily create a random permutation, and then chain the cards up based on that. Permuting a linked list can be a little harder.

As I said, I don't know the application, so I have no idea if this good or bad advice, but I have put some example code below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DECK_SIZE 52

struct card
{
    char suit;
    char const *face;
    struct card *next;
};

struct card *alloc_deck(void)
{
    static char const *suite = "CDHS";
    static char const *face[] = {
        "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
        "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K",
        NULL};
    struct card *deck = malloc(DECK_SIZE * sizeof *deck);

    struct card *card = deck;
    for (char const *s = suite; *s; s++)
    {
        for (char const **f = face; *f; f++)
        {
            *card = (struct card){
                .suit = *s,
                .face = *f,
                .next = card + 1 // point to next card
            };
            card++;
        }
    }

    // last card should point to zero
    (card - 1)->next = NULL;

    return deck;
}

void print_card_list(struct card *deck)
{
    for (struct card *card = deck; card; card = card->next)
    {
        printf("%s%c\n", card->face, card->suit);
    }
}

void print_deck_array(struct card *deck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%c\n", deck[i].face, deck[i].suit);
    }
}

struct card *shuffle(struct card *deck)
{
    static int perm_init;
    static int perm[DECK_SIZE];
    if (!perm_init)
    {
        perm_init = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            perm[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // permute indices
    for (int i = DECK_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        int temp = perm[i];
        perm[i] = perm[j];
        perm[j] = temp;
    }

    // chain up the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        deck[perm[i]].next = &deck[perm[i + 1]];
    }
    deck[perm[DECK_SIZE - 1]].next = NULL; // terminate chain

    return &deck[perm[0]]; // return first in chain
}

int main(void)
{
    struct card *deck = alloc_deck();

    printf("Allocated list:\n");
    print_card_list(deck);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Allocated array:\n");
    print_deck_array(deck);
    printf("\n");

    struct card *card = shuffle(deck);
    printf("Shuffled deck:\n");
    print_card_list(card);
    printf("\n");

    card = shuffle(deck);
    printf("Second shuffled deck:\n");
    print_card_list(card);
    printf("\n");

    free(deck); // free deck as a whole

    return 0;
}
```